# Sendmail only sending locally

Tags: linux, centos7, sendmail

I wrote a script to send me an email if an existing process is not available, so I installed sendmail as suggested elsewhere. I know why I'm having the issue I'm having, but either I do not know how to solve it, or I'm having a lapse in memory. Whenever I run:

```
root# sendmail myemail@mydomain.com
test
.
root#
```

I only receive the email locally on the server that has sendmail installed, and not to myemail@mydomain.com. The logs show normally 5-6 entries that show what looks like this:

```
timestamp myemail@mydomain.com... User unknown

timestamp sendmail[17220]: v2OIL5pc017220: to=myemail@mydomain.com, delay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=0, dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown

timestamp sendmail[17220]: v2OIL5pc017220: from=root, size=5, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201703241821.v2OIL5pc017220@localhost.localdomain>, relay=root@localhost

timestamp sendmail[17220]: v2OIL5pc017220: v2OIL5pd017220: DSN: User unknown

timestamp sendmail[17220]: v2OIL5pd017220: to=root, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=31029, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
```

What appears to be the issue to me is that sendmail starts to send the email correctly, but then sends the email locally. It sets the relay as the local host, then changes the to: to root, which I do not understand why. I added a record in my hosts file, as well as added mail.mydomain.com as a SMART_HOST in the sendmail.mc file.

For testing purposes I made an accept all policy in iptables. When I perform a tcpdump I can see DNS requests reaching out to my DNS servers, but never do I see any SMTP traffic. Linux is so awesome, but is so frustrating at times...

Comment: It seems your sendmail thinks it is handling emails for @mydomain.com hence the mail says "local". You should configure it only as a relay host, to forward emails where they belong or to your ISP SMTP server for example (if I have understood you correctly)

Comment: This is what I was assuming as well, but would not setting the mail.mydomain.com in the SMART_HOST direct it to the relay?

Comment: It should I think, but how does `mail.mydomain.com` resolves? Are you sure, on this box, that it does not loop back to the server itself?